# Migrated from Magento1.9 to Magento2.4.2

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch, sales

That was 3 weeks ago. Sales dropped. Did that happen to you ?
Could it be IT related ? We have no issue so far. Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked organic rankings? Can take a few weeks for Google to fully re-index. We always put aside 4/5 weeks or dropped sales.